# Converting Java Date to Epoch gives wrong result

Tags: java, date, format, converters, epoch

I am converting java Date object to epoch using code :

```
        String str = "" + date;
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date formateDate = df.parse(str);
        long epoch = formateDate.getTime();
        return epoch;
```

If I test this with value `2013-04-26 08:34:55.705` then it gives Long as `1359189295705` which is actually `Sat, 26 Jan 2013 08:34:55 GMT` but its Friday today why does it say that its Saturday on 26th January 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's using *January* not *April*. January 26th was indeed a Saturday. It's given you the wrong month because your date format is wrong:

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

You're using `mm` for the month, when you should be using `MM`. The date format should be:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Your format didn't specify the month anywhere, so presumably it just defaulted to January.

Answer (score 2):

The format for month is wrong, should be `yyyy-MM-dd`, so it's defaulting to the first month for you.